# DataContractSerializer documentation

Tags: documentation, datacontractserializer

I'm looking for a good in depth documentation/how-to for DataContractSerializer. Google turns up a number of related articles but nothing jumped out at me. (I'm not looking for the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx))

A little clarification: I have never use serialization in .NET but have a working app that does that I need to update/modify. I have a fairly good Idea how *I* would do what I need to do if *I had designed the serialization system* but I'd rather not hunt trough a pile of MSDN class documentation looking for how they expect me to do it. The MSDN stuff works well for figuring out how something works (as does Google because at that point you have a specific term to Google) What I would like is a well done "here is how it works and this is all the details" document targeted at showing me how to fit the pieces together rather than figuring out how they work. I'm afraid what I'm looking for is a bit of an "I'll know it when I see it" thing, and I have never had good luck Googeling for that sort of thing.

I'm particularly interested in specific pages that people have used and personally found very useful. *If you are thinking of something particular right now (before going to Google) that is what I'm looking for. If not...*

Answer (score 2):

Try this MSDN link instead, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

> but I'd rather not hunt trough a pile
>   of MSDN class documentation looking
>   for how they expect me to do it.

It's Microsoft, what do you expect??? You ARE expected to use it the way they want it. :)

Comment: I don't care who wrote it as long as it's easy to read, correct and detailed.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/) is very helpful because it shows the benefits of `DataContractSerializer` in contrast to `XmlSerializer`.  This was the first article I used when learning about WCF and `DataContractSerializer`.

Not to be disparaging but isn't a Google search the best way to get this kind of information?  The most helpful and informative links will be on the first page as those will be the most linked and visited.

Comment: Google has yet to master the art of recognizing good writing. It's good at spotting popular writing but that's not what I'm looking for. For example given "compiler design" Google puts the dragon book (its Wikipedia article actually) 5th. On less common topics that gets even worse.

Comment: That seems to cover some of the "how" but even the tile focus on the "why". As I have never used either DataContractSerializer or XmlSerializer and am being told to use DataContractSerializer the "why" is of little or no interest to me.